# Drawing a curve on a 3-D surface graph

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

I have created a  surface graph in MATLAB which I have projected on to X-Y axis.  I want to find the equation of a line that follows the yellow region in the following graph. That is I want to find the equation of a curved line like the one displayed from the black curve.
Is there a way for me to draw a curved line on this surface graph and then obtain the equation of that curve.
If it is a line in MATLAB I think I can do it by `Insert-> Line`.  Is there a similar way for me to draw a curve on the surface graph?

[image]

Comment: From the top of my head: I'd go with a `find` to search out the yellow bit, then use `lscov` to fit a line through it (though you'd need to know the function form of your line for that)

Comment: Use [`contour`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`contour`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html). Note that, as per the documentation, you have to duplicate the value that defines the desired level:

```
x = linspace(0,pi,200);
y = linspace(0,pi/2,200);
z = bsxfun(@times, sin(x), sin(y.')); %'// example data
imagesc(z); %// plot image
hold on
value = .5; %// desired level
h = contour(z,[value value],'k'); %// plot contour for that level
```

[image]